# SuiteCRM 8 Header Submenu External Link

Tags: php, suitecrm

In SuiteCRM 8 I have added a submenu link under the 'Emails' header menu by creating the file public/legacy/custom/Extension/modules/Emails/Ext/Menus/menu.ext.php. The code I used works for internal navigation, but when I try to incorporate an external link, such as 'https://www.my-external-link.com' it stops SuiteCRM from working. How can I modify my code to enable the use of external links?

```
<?php
global $current_user;
global $mod_strings, $app_strings;
$module_menu = array();

// Each index of module_menu must be an array of:
// the link url, display text for the link, and the icon name.


if (ACLController::checkAccess('Emails', 'edit', true)) {
    $module_menu[]=array("index.php?module=Emails&action=ComposeView&return_module=Emails&return_action=index", $mod_strings['LNK_NEW_SEND_EMAIL'],"Create", 'Emails');
}
if (ACLController::checkAccess('Emails', 'list', true)) {
    $module_menu[]=array("index.php?module=Emails&action=index&return_module=Emails&return_action=DetailView", $mod_strings['LNK_VIEW_MY_INBOX'],"List", 'Emails');
}
if (ACLController::checkAccess('Emails', 'list', true)) {
    $module_menu[]=array("https://www.my-external-link.com", $mod_strings['LBL_LIST_STATUS'],"List", 'Emails');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Using JavaScript to open the external link in a new tab, hope this helps

```
<?php
global $current_user;
global $mod_strings, $app_strings;
$module_menu = array();

// Each index of module_menu must be an array of:
// the link url, display text for the link, and the icon name.


if (ACLController::checkAccess('Emails', 'edit', true)) {
    $module_menu[]=array("index.php?module=Emails&action=ComposeView&return_module=Emails&return_action=index", $mod_strings['LNK_NEW_SEND_EMAIL'],"Create", 'Emails');
}
if (ACLController::checkAccess('Emails', 'list', true)) {
    $module_menu[]=array("index.php?module=Emails&action=index&return_module=Emails&return_action=DetailView", $mod_strings['LNK_VIEW_MY_INBOX'],"List", 'Emails');
}
if (ACLController::checkAccess('Emails', 'list', true)) {
    $module_menu[]=array("javascript:void(window.open('https://www.my-external-link.com','_blank'));", $mod_strings['LBL_LIST_STATUS'],"List", 'Emails');
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, when I use this code or anything other than a known SuiteCRM URL such as index.php?module=Emails&action=index&return_module=Emails&return_action=DetailView in the array and do a 'Quick Repair and Rebuild' the site breaks, and you can not see the menu or the content of the page. I've even tried just adding index.php as the URL, and that breaks the site.